# integration of Raspberry Pi v2 camera with Jetson Nano

Tags: nvidia-jetson-nano

We would like to integrate Raspberry Pi v2 CSI camera 8MP with Jetson Nano with carrier board.
The end user has below requirements:

Able to see the live camera feed from desktop and mobile devices without any lag.
Able to run the AI inference on the live feed for object detection or classification.

From hardware point of view, how are we going to support the live feed?
Is it through HDMI, ethernet cable, Wifi , web server etc or through g-streamer library?

Answer (score 0):

Stack exchange is for software. You might find someone able to help you out but you're better off checking out some of the other stack exchanges e.g. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or maybe
https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/